# Identityserver4 authorization across multiple applications (Grafana, .net API)

Tags: .net-core, oauth, identityserver4, openid-connect, grafana

I have the following setup:

- grafana with auth based on generic oauth (https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/auth/generic-oauth/),
- identityserver4,
- .net core API.

I want to develop custom front-end panel plugin for grafana that uses logged in user credentials to authorize calls to my API. Accoriding to docs, Grafana stores token in a cookie named `grafana_session` (https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/configuration/#login_cookie_name). Also `with credentials` flag is set to `include` the cookie togheter with calls (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#sending_a_request_with_credentials_included).
Here's my identityserver4 clients configuration:

```
// Grafana client
new Client
{
    ClientId = "grafana_client_id",
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
    ClientSecrets = { new Secret("grafana_client_secret".Sha256()) },
    AllowedScopes = { "openid", "profile", "email", "grafana_role" },
    RedirectUris = { "https://localhost:3000/login/generic_oauth" },
    RequirePkce = false,
},
```

```
// API
new Client
{
    ClientId = "myAPI_id",
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
    ClientSecrets = { new Secret("myAPI_secret".Sha256()) },
    AllowedScopes = { "openid", "profile", "email", "myAPI" },
    RedirectUris = { "https://localhost:5005/signin-oidc" },
    RequirePkce = false,
},
```

Auth setup on API side:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "Cookies";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
})
    .AddCookie()
    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
    {
        options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
        options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001";
        options.ClientId = "myAPI_id";
        options.ClientSecret = "myAPI_secret";
        options.ResponseType = "code";
        options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
        options.Scope.Add("openid");
        options.Scope.Add("profile");
        options.Scope.Add("myAPI");
    });
```

I'm able to authorize user with grafana (`id_token` is saved in cookies), but when calling API from the browser `/connect/authorize` is getting called again with settings for API client (that one with `ClientId = myAPI_id`). Then, nothing happes, API endpoint is not getting called (it looks like API is waiting for user to login again). Is it possible to set up auth to use Grafana token to authorize calls to my API? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just for clarification - I'm not able to get `access_token` that IS generates and token that is saved in cookies is not `id_token` but Grafana interval auth token.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use OIDC in your API. Just add authorization and authentication in startup:

```
services.AddAuthentication("bearer")
            .AddJwtBearer("bearer", options =>
            {
                options.Authority = myIDS4URL;                    
                options.Events = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnMessageReceived = context =>
                    {

                        var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];

                        var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) && (path.StartsWithSegments("/myendpoint")))
                        {
                            context.Token = accessToken;
                        }
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnTokenValidated = context =>
                    {
                        var token = context.SecurityToken as JwtSecurityToken;
                        if (token != null)
                        {
                            ClaimsIdentity identity = context.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
                            if (identity != null)
                            {
                                identity.AddClaim(new Claim("access_token", token.RawData));
                            }
                        }

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };

                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    NameClaimType = "name",
                    RoleClaimType = "role"
                };
            });
```

and then:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("ApiScope", policy =>
            {
                policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                policy.RequireClaim("scope", "myAPI_id");
            });
        });
```

Comment: Yes, that would work when I'd be able to get access token that Grafana gets after authenticating with identity server. After, some deeper research I found out that Grafana stores `access_token` from IS in it's internal database and as far as I know it is not possible to get it from JavaScript panel. My solution for that case is that I'm using Grafana as auth authority - my API asks Grafana if it's `grafana session` token is still valid.